# Deleted Files App

Tags: files

I have deleted libzeitgeist and somehow also the Files app was removed. What to do now? How to get it back?
Ubuntu 18.10 Desktop
Minimal installation

Comment: Run `sudo apt install nautilus`.

Answer (score 3):

To install files a.k.a. nautilus, run

```
sudo apt install nautilus
```